# How to print every second line of the text in .txt file using vb 6

Tags: loops, printing, vb6

I have a program that reads all info from .txt file and after this showing in MsgBox. Need to know, how to print every second line (every second name) from this file and show in MsgBox. Here is my code:

```
Sub Printed
Dim sFileText As String
Dim sFinal as String
Dim iFileNo As Integer
iFileNo = FreeFile
Open "D:\Information\data.txt" For Input As #iFileNo
Do While Not EOF(iFileNo)
  Input #iFileNo, sFileText
sFinal = sFinal & sFileText & vbCRLF
Loop
MsgBox sFinal
Close #iFileNo

End Sub
```

*Here is, how .txt file looks*

[image: Here is, how .txt file looks]

`Here is how it showing now in MsgBox`: [image: printed info now]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Printed
    Dim sFileText As String
    Dim sFinal as String
    Dim iFileNo As Integer
    Dim fIgnoreLine As Boolean
    iFileNo = FreeFile
    
    ' fIgnoreLine = True    ' uncomment this line if you want to print every even line
    Open "D:\Information\data.txt" For Input As #iFileNo
    Do While Not EOF(iFileNo)
        Line Input #iFileNo, sFileText
        if Not fIgnoreLine then sFinal = sFinal & sFileText & vbCRLF
        fIgnoreLine = Not fIgnoreLine
    Loop
    MsgBox sFinal
    Close #iFileNo

End Sub
```